# How to push the values with open brace and close brace

Tags: jquery, push

**My answer shows like 1,2,3,1,2,1,4,5** (without open and close tag)

but **i want to show like this model [1,2,3][1,2][1,4,5]**

want with open close tag, because want to seperate the option values to store in database.

my script

```
var foo = [];
$('.box22').each(function(x,v){
 var temp =[]
  $(v).find("select[name='category[]'] > option:selected").each(function(i, selected){
  temp.push($(selected).val(),[]);
 });
 foo.push(temp);
 alert(foo);
});
```

my view file code

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)  { ?>
<div class="box22">
  <div class="mcm">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Myself" id="coworkers" name="coworkers[]" />
   <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="select2">
    <select id="category_<?php echo $i; ?>" name="category[]" class="chosen-select ref-sel1" multiple >
   <?php
    foreach($genre as $gen){
      echo '<option value='.$gen->genre_id.'>'.$gen->genre_name.'</option>';
    } 
   ?>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: what is your output with this script?

Comment: in alert it shows 1,2,3,1,2,1,4,5

Comment: @shruthi why do you need to alert that data?

Comment: post html code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
var foo = [];
  $('.box22').each(function(x, v) {
    var temp = []
    $(v).find("select[name='category[]'] > option:selected").each(function(i, selected) {
      temp.push($(selected).val());
    });
    text = '[' + temp.join(',') + ']'
    foo.push(text);

  });
  alert(foo.join(''));
```

[demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/t2envf00/2/)

Comment: Thank you. Got answer from here.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var foo = new Array();
 var temp =new Array();
$('.box22').each(function(x,v){

   $(v).find("select[name='category[]'] > option:selected").each(function(i, selected){

       temp={
           p: '[' +$(selected).val()+']',
              }
         });
   foo.push(temp.p);
   alert(foo);
});
```

Comment: what key does the `$(selected).val();` goth?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this

```
var foo = [];
            $('.box22').each(function(x,v){
            var temp =[];   
             $(v).find('select  option').each(function() {
                 var selected = $(this).attr("selected");
                 var selectedvalue = $(this).attr("value");
                if(selected = "selected")
                {
                    temp.push(selectedvalue);
                }
             });
            foo[x] = temp;
                 console.log(temp);
            });
```